# Copy and paste from sh1 to sh2 when 2 condition meet (GOOGLE SCRIPT)

Tags: google-apps-script, copy-paste

Please help me with the below:
Starting from row 7 of sheet1: if column E is NOT BLANK and column D is BLANK then I need copy from columns A:L to last empty row of sheet2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to check the columns "D" and "E" on "Sheet1".
- When the values of column "D" and "E" are empty and not empty, you want to copy the row to the next row of last row in "Sheet2".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

I this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const values = sheet1.getRange("A7:L" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((ar, r) => {
    if (r[3].toString() == "" && r[4].toString() != "") ar.push(r);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: @@Tanaike: That's perfect but please help: 1// How to let scrip stop if there's no condition met?  2// Is there any way to get the value of cell H4 at column L if condition met (instead copy value from A:L but copy A:K and L = value of cell H4?

Comment: @@Tanaike: I close this and post a new question. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66460884/copy-and-paste-in-google-script]