# Copy and Paste in GOOGLE SCRIPT

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

*I want to check the columns "D" and "E" on "Sheet1".
*IF: => the values of column "D" and "E" are empty and not empty => I want to copy the row from A:I from Sheet1 to the next row of last row in "Sheet2";
*If there's no condition met => DO NOTHING

The code you provided is good but got an error when no condition met.

I want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

[SAMPLE1_UPDATED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V4sF.png)
[SAMPLE2_UPDATED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSfTh.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue and your goal. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about them, can you provide more information including your current script and the sample situations of input and output you expect?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot understand about `If there's no condition met => DO NOTHING`. I apologize for this. In this case, when the values of column "D" and "E" are not empty or empty, you don't want to copy the rows, even when the condition of other rows is filled. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about `If there's no condition met => DO NOTHING`. So I proposed 2 patterns as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If those were not the direction you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. Because when I tested the script, no error occurs. I apologize for this. In order correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, when you comment, can you comment to my answer? By this, I can confirm your comment by the notification.

Comment: By the way, about your replying of `Patten1: I got same error at this line sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values); `, in my proposed answer, I don't use the variable of `values` and the script of `sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values)`. So I'm worry that you might not use my proposed script. How about this?

Comment: Thank you for replying. At first, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot see your sample Spreadsheet. And, when you comment, can you comment to my answer? By this, I can confirm your comment by the notification. How about this?

Comment: And also, your replying of `Patten1: I got same error at this line sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);`, in my proposed answer, I don't use the variable of `values` and the script of `sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values)`. How about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to check the columns "D" and "E" on "Sheet1".
- When the values of column "D" and "E" are empty and not empty, you want to copy the columns "A" to "I" of the row to the next row of last row in "Sheet2".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

About `If there's no condition met => DO NOTHING`, I'm not sure which you want to achieve as follows.

1. When the values of column "D" and "E" are not empty or empty, you don't want to copy, even when the condition of other rows is filled.
2. When the values of column "D" and "E" are not empty or empty, you don't want to copy the rows. But the rows with the filled condition are copied.

So, in this answer, I proposed the following 2 patterns.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, when the values of column "D" and "E" are not empty or empty, the script is not run, even when the condition of other rows is filled.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const obj = sheet1.getRange("A1:I" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, r) => {
    o[(r[3].toString() == "" && r[4].toString() != "") ? "trueCondition" : "falseCondition"].push(r);
    return o;
  }, {falseCondition: [], trueCondition: []});
  if (obj.falseCondition.length == 0) {
    sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, obj.trueCondition.length, obj.trueCondition[0].length).setValues(obj.trueCondition);
  }
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, when the values of column "D" and "E" are not empty or empty, the rows are not copied. But the rows with the filled condition are copied.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const obj = sheet1.getRange("A1:I" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, r) => {
    o[(r[3].toString() == "" && r[4].toString() != "") ? "trueCondition" : "falseCondition"].push(r);
    return o;
  }, {falseCondition: [], trueCondition: []});
  sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, obj.trueCondition.length, obj.trueCondition[0].length).setValues(obj.trueCondition);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the values of "Sheet1" are retrieved from the 1st row. When you want to change the start row, please modify `"A1:I"` to your actual situation.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

### Added:

About your additional following 2 sample images,

[image]

[image]

how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const obj = sheet1.getRange("A1:I" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, r) => {
    if ((r[3].toString() != "" && r[4].toString() != "") || (r[3].toString() == "" && r[4].toString() == "") || (r[3].toString() != "" && r[4].toString() == "")) {
      o.falseCondition.push(r);
    } else if ((r[3].toString() == "" && r[4].toString() != "")) {
      o.trueCondition.push(r);
    }
    return o;
  }, {falseCondition: [], trueCondition: []});
  if (obj.trueCondition.length > 0) {
    sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, obj.trueCondition.length, obj.trueCondition[0].length).setValues(obj.trueCondition);
  }
}
```

- In this case, you can see the rows which were not copied by `console.log(obj.falseCondition)`.

Comment: I added the pictures of 2 samples since you can not ôen the link

Comment: @tt3 Thank you for replying and adding the sample images. I have to apologize for my poor understanding. From your added images, I cannot understand about the logic for achieving your goal of `If there's no condition met => DO NOTHING`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? By the way, you want to use 2 columns of "C" and "D" as the column "C"?

Comment: If D is Blank > do notthing

Comment: @tt3 Thank you for replying. From `If D is Blank > do notthing`, I cannot still understand about the logic for achieving your goal. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? By the way, you want to use 2 columns of "C" and "D" as the column "C"?

Comment: Sorry for confusing. I have updated two images and hope this help.

Comment: @tt3 Thank you for replying. I would like to check it.

Comment: @tt3 Thank you for replying. From your added 2 samples, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: It worked and I know you can make it work (just because my question was not clear). I added this line to the end of your scrip and it only got one at the very last row but I want to add to every single row when copy to sheet 2 => {sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow() , 11).activate().setFormula('=\'Sheet3\'!B4');}

Comment: @tt3 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.